# Removing all Matching Classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have an li element that will have something along the lines of this for a declaration

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix">
```

And I can dynamically change the color of the module by adding on classes (That are provided dynamically through DB calls) the end result being

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix module-green">
```

or

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix module-default">
```

Well I am fine with changing the color by adding on a new module-WHATEVER class but what I would like to do is remove any class that matches module-XXXX so it starts with a clean slate and then add on the class module-crimson.

So how do I remove all classes that match module-xxx first ? Keeping in mind I don't want to remove the base module class.

EDIT:

I basically need the method of doing a clean sweep on any module-  class:

Before Execution

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix module-default">
```

After Clean Sweep

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix">
```

Then Add Class and Final Result

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix module-green">
```

Thanks.

-Seth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/onoxa/7

**DEMO 2:** http://jsbin.com/onoxa/8

```
$(function() {
    $("li").each(function(e) {     
    var classes = this.className.replace(/module-\w+/gi, '' );
        $(this).attr('class', classes);
    });
});​
```

---

```
$("li").each(function(e) {
    var classes = this.className.replace(/module-\w+/gi, '');
    $(this).attr('class', classes + ' module-green');

});
```

ouput this:

```
<li class="module ui-helper-fix">
```

Comment: This is close, but what I would like to do is basically everytime I try to add a new color class (module-green, module-default, etc.) I do a clean sweep of that elements classes for any matching "module-" classes.

Comment: so you basicaly want remove all the module-xxx and leave just module! right!?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var newClass = "module-green";
$("li").attr("class","module ui-helper-fix").addClass(newClass);
```

Comment: This would technically work, however there are certain occasions where it wouldn't just be module and ui-helper-fix included in the class list. But Nevertheless +1

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeModule(selector, module_name) {
    var that = selector;
    var classes = $(selector).attr('class').split(' ');
    $.each(classes, function(index, thisClass){
        if (thisClass.indexOf('module-') !== -1) {
            $(that).removeClass(classes[index])
        }
    });
    $(that).addClass(module_name);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('li').click(function(){
        changeModule(this, 'module-green');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just an old post, but since jQuery 1.4 you can provide a [matching function to `.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-functionindex--class)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/MJdRy/

```
$('.module')
    .removeClass(function(i,c) {
        return c.match(/module-\w+/gi).join(' ');
    })
    .addClass('module-green');
```

*based on [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691960/1037948)*

It looks clunkier than the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2783518/1037948) but it's the "jQuery way".