# jQuery - remove all matching classes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove all matching classes running `each()` function.

I am selecting matching class like `[class*="ui-id-"]`. But my below jquery code wont work:

**My buggy code:**

```
jQuery('#builder [class*="ui-id-"]').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('[class*="ui-id-"]');
});
```

Please correct my code so that it can remove all matching class `ui-id-`

Comment: @DavidThomas the OP is using 'each' on a id selector '#builder'

Comment: @mck yes it was working, previously I tried that but dont know why it was not worked.

Comment: please telll me the full form of OP

Comment: ^Original Poster, @DavidThomas, sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$('#builder [class*="ui-id-"]').removeClass(function(i, j) {
           return j.match(/ui-id-/g).join(" ");
});
```

should remove all the matched classes.

Comment: Edited answer. Please check

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would unfortunately be the big way, iterate all elements:

```
jQuery('#builder').find('*').each(function() {
    var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);

    $.each(classes, function(i, c) {
        if (c.indexOf('ui-id-') === 0) {
            $(this).removeClass(c);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need each loop here

try this

```
 jQuery('[class*="ui-id-"]').removeClass('[class*="ui-id-"]');
```

i removed the `#builder`, it will be easy to figure out the correct answer if you post you related html code too

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#builder [class^='ui-id-']").removeClass();
```

This will remove all the classes starts wiht `ui-id-` present in `#builder`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.ui-id-').removeClass('ui-id-');
```

Comment: Did you actually test this? It looks like bogus to me.

Comment: Above will work if `classname` is same, will not work for pattern http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/NbqUg/1/